# Some problems with SDWebImage

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

When I used the method load image, after the image gets downloaded, it does not show until I select or scroll the cell, but if I don't set the placeholderImage to nil, it works well. I don't know what's wrong with. Here's my code:

```
[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:(my url) placeholderImage:nil];
```

Some problems with SDWebImage

Comment: could you try to put this method on main_queue?

Comment: I used SDWebImage，I've seen his code，he used (dispathch_main_aync_safe)

Comment: @CongTran I've tried only the cell.imageView had the problem

Comment: Can you try to remove `dispathch_main_aync_safe ` block, let write it outside. maybe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's weird, but you can try `[cell setNeedsLayout];` after you set the image to reload all the cell views.

I guess you have all the calls inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: You are rigiht,it works well when I use this method:' [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://pic2.ooopic.com/01/03/51/25b1OOOPIC19.jpg"] placeholderImage:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        [cell layoutSubviews];
    }];'

Comment: But I still don't know why ,if the placeholderImage isn't nil,it works well even if hasn't the code   [cell layoutSubviews] .

Answer (score 0):

use completion block to change the image view.

```
[myImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMG_PLACEHOLDER] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {}];
```

use this in your project and try.

Comment: thanks,I should inside the code `[cell layoutSubviews]` in the completion block.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use another method to do this, as an example:

```
[_theImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_imageUrl]]
```

Comment: sorry ,it has the same problem.

Comment: @hmxxxhhh  oh,It looks strange，make sure whether  your tableview has some problem